# Confusion related to auto and static variables

Tags: c++, c, static, auto, storage-class-specifier

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a=10;
    {    printf("%d",a);
         int a=20;
         printf("%d",a);
    }
    printf(" %d",a);
    return 0;
}

Output:10 20 10
```

In the above code I understand that the visibility of variable a(inside inner block) has scope only within that block therefore I get that particular output. 
But the variable a which is declared outside that block should have its scope even within the inner block...Therefore how is it possible for me to again type `int a=20;`
Shouldn't it give me an error like "redefinition of a" and "previous declaration of a was here". Like if I use

```
int b=10;
int b=15;
```

My second problem is this

```
void main() {
 static int a=10;

    {
         printf("%d ",a);
         static int a=20;
         printf("%d",a);
    }
    printf(" %d",a);

}
```

Apart from the same doubt as the previous code about why I'm not getting an error like "redefinition of a", This is my doubt related to this code.

For the above code i get the same `Output: 10 20 10` but what I was expecting was

```
10 20 20
```

I mean in the inner block once static int a is reinitialized to 20 shouldn't it be the same value even after it exits the block? because the a static variable's scope is throughout the entire program.

Comment: In the inner block you are creating a brand new static variable whose scope is the brackets. If you want to change the value of the outer static variable, simply do `a=20`, not `static int a=20;`. The compiler can change the names of variables at compile time, so those two `a` variables you have there would have totally different names after compile time.

Comment: Yes, I did figure out that was the only explanation but again my question here is how come a brand new variable is created? If the scope and visibility of my outer (static int a) is throughout the entire program then for my inner (static int a) shouldn't it report an error something like redefinition of a not allowed. And yes I am aware about the a=20.
Hope you can understand what I'm trying to say cause its hard for me to put it into words.

Comment: If two variables with the same name are declared in different scopes, the compiler can figure out the difference and they will be treated as separate variables. If two variables with the same name are declared in the same scope, the compiler can't figure out the difference and will report an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for the first problem: It is called variable shadowing. From Wikipedia:

> variable shadowing occurs when a variable declared within a certain
>   scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a
>   variable declared in an outer scope.

Simply put, when you create a variable with the same name but in other scope it shadows the previous variable.

About the second problem - here is a fine example:

```
// static1.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void showstat( int curr ) {
   static int nStatic;    // Value of nStatic is retained
                          // between each function call
   nStatic += curr;
   cout << "nStatic is " << nStatic << endl;
}

int main() {
   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
      showstat( i );
}
```

Output:

nStatic is 0

nStatic is 1

nStatic is 3

nStatic is 6

nStatic is 10

Comment: The designers of C# decided to forbid this.  http://ericlippert.com/2014/09/25/confusing-errors-for-a-confusing-feature-part-one/#more-2371

Comment: You can enable a warning for this on gcc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/958646/2394945

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you.
But I still don't understand why the developers would even bother having variable shadowing,It doesn't seem to have any advantage.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/215091/why-do-programming-languages-allow-shadowing-hiding-of-variables-and-functions

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a=10;
    {    printf("%d",a);
         int a=20;
         printf("%d",a);
    }
    printf(" %d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The second `a` is in a different scope, as you seem to already understand. The "redefinition of a" error only applies when you define two variables with the same name **in the same scope**.

```
void main() {
    static int a=10;

    {
         printf("%d ",a);
         static int a=20;
         printf("%d",a);
    }
    printf(" %d",a);

}
```

Again, the `a` inside the inner block only has scope within that block. If you re-enter the same block, `a` will continue to have the same value because you declared it as `static`. However, outside of the block, you will use the value of first variable `a`. This illustrates the difference between a variable's **scope** and its **lifetime**.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the quick reply, it cleared my doubts on the use of static.