# How to error trap a string array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, error-handling

After the user is prompted to make a selection and they enter 3 they are then asked to enter a name from a list given.
If they enter a name that is not on the list the program needs to output a statement saying that the name entered is not on the list

I have tried everything I could think of and the program works fine if I remove the error trapping.

The issue is inside the `int SpecTime` function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double FastSkier(double [], string[], int);     //Function for finding fastest skier
double AvgTime(double[], int);                  //Function for finding Average
int SpecTime(double[], string[], int);          //Function for finding the time of the name entered
int SkiAndTime(double[], string[], int);        //Function to list all Skiers and their times

int main()
{
    const int Size = 5; //size of arrays
    string name[Size] = { "Leela" , "Sarah" , "Anna" , "Keesha" , "Heidi" };    //array for Skier names
    double time[Size] = {  2.03   ,  2.40   ,  1.85  ,  1.90    ,  2.50 };      //array for Skier times
    int choice;

    for (int count = 1;; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter 1 to find the fastest Skier" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 2 for the average time of the Skiers" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 3 to find the time of a specific Skier \n";
        cout << "Enter 4 to display all Skiers and their times \n";
        cout << "Enter any other number to end the program \n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
            FastSkier(time, name, Size);
        else if (choice == 2)
            AvgTime(time, Size);
        else if (choice == 3)
            SpecTime(time, name, Size);
        else if (choice == 4)
            SkiAndTime(time, name, Size);
        else
            return 0;
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}



double FastSkier(double time[], string name[], int Size)
{
    int Loc;                                    //location of data within array, value determined by for-loop
    int count;                                  //Counter
    double fastest=time[0];                     //variable to find fastest time for Skier, initialized at first value of time
    for (count = 1; count < Size; count++)      //cycles through all values of time comparing each one to find the lowest value
    {
        if (time[count] < fastest)
            Loc = count-1;        //subtract 1 from count to adjust for array index
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The fastest Skier is " << name[Loc] << " with a time of " << fixed << setprecision(2) << time[Loc] << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}


double AvgTime(double time[], int Size)
{
    int Loc;            //location of data within array, acts as a counter in this function 
    double Avg;         //Average
    double sum = 0;     //sum of all values within time[]

    for (Loc = 0; Loc < Size; Loc++)
        sum += time[Loc];
    Avg = sum / Size;

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The average time for Skiers is " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Avg << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}


int SpecTime(double time[], string name[], int Size)
{
    string Skier;   //Name of Skier entered by user
    int Loc=0;
    bool List = true;

    cout << "Skiers \n";

    for (int Loc = 0; Loc < Size; Loc++)     //For-loop used to output and display all names of Skiers
    {
        cout << "    " << name[Loc] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter the name of the Skier to view their time \n";
    cin >> Skier;

    for (int Loc = 0; Loc < Size; Loc++)    //For-loop used to find the desired Skier's time
    {
        if (Skier == name[Loc])
        {
            cout << Skier << " has the time " << fixed << setprecision(2) << time[Loc] << endl;
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        }

    }
    if (Skier != name[Loc])    //error trap for inputted names that are not listed
    {
        cout << "The name you entered is not a current competitor in this competition \n";
        cout << "\n";
        //break;
    }
    return 0;
}


int SkiAndTime(double time[], string name[], int Size)
{
    cout << "Skiers             Times" << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    for (int All = 0; All< Size; All++)
        cout << name[All] << "             " << fixed << setprecision(2) << time[All] << endl;

    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you not know how to check if the name is on the list?

Comment: No I don't know how to. Everything I've tried either doesn't trigger the error message or triggers the message even when a correct input is entered

Comment: Prepare shortest code example next time and describe you problem more in detail next time. You will get answer much faster. Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Variable `Loc`, which is created in seconds line of the `SpecTime`, is not the variable `Loc`, which is used in loops.
Take a look at line

```
for (int Loc = 0; Loc < Size; Loc++)
```

`int Loc = 0` means that you create a new variable which shadows the original one. Change it to `Loc = 0` and the code should work properly.

---

More about variable shadowing: [In C++, when can two variables of the same name be visible in the same scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958625/in-c-when-can-two-variables-of-the-same-name-be-visible-in-the-same-scope)